# Migrating Wordpress + Woocommerce to Drupal + Drupal Commerce

Tags: wordpress, drupal, woocommerce, migration

I need to migrate all the user detail including password, order history, billing address from WordPress to Drupal commerce.

I am not sure how to start it. Can anyone point me to the right direction?